# Is there any way to cyclically update only a <div> content in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm using a div with a `<li>` element inside where I add some dynamically created elements (localStorage keys to be more specific). I want to update the div every "x" seconds but only the `<div>`, not the whole page. I know that it can be done with Ajax and JQuery (`$( "#here" ).load(window.location.href + " #here" );`).

But is there any way to do this whit pure js?

**UPDATE**

The specific case is that im picking all the localstorage keys and appending them to a list inside a div. When i use like this (window.onload) it works fine. But I want to update it cyclically. If i use a "setinterval" or a button to call the function the previous keys appends repeatedly. (like: file 1.... then: file 1, file 1 file 2 ... then: file 1 file 1 file 2 file 1 file 1 file 1 file 2 file 3)

```
window.onload = function cargararchivos() {
    localstorage = []
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var elemento_lista = document.createElement('li')
    elemento_lista.innerHTML = keys[i]
    var lista = document.getElementById('lista_archivos')
    lista.appendChild(elemento_lista)
    localstorage[ keys[i] ] = localStorage.getItem( keys[i] )

    elemento_lista.onclick = function() 
    {alert(JSON.parse(localStorage[keys[i]]))}}
};
```

Comment: Look at the source for jQuery load (hint: it's written in pure js)

Comment: you dont need any `ajax` since you are getting data from `localStorage`. use `setTimeout` and do some coding first

Comment: What exactly being updated HTML elements (ex. `<div>`), a value of an element's attribute (ex. `<div data-value="0"...`), or the text within an element (ex. `<div>Text</div>`)? BTW it's invalid HTML to have anything but a `<ol>` or `<ul>` to be the parent of a `<li>`.. Also can you please post a [mcve] for use so that we can give you an accurate answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your method works the first time, but doesn't work after that is because the method adds DOM nodes. After the second call, you're seeing DOM nodes from *both the first call and second call*. After the third call, you'd see nodes from the first, second, and third calls... and so on.

If you want to repeatedly call a method like cargararchivos() that adds DOM nodes, you must first remove any DOM elements that have been previously added. I've updated your code, assuming `lista_archivos` starts empty (no child elements):

```
function cargararchivos() {
    localstorage = []
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    var lista = document.getElementById('lista_archivos')

    // Ensure any previously added DOM nodes are removed.
    while (lista.firstChild) {
        lista.removeChild(lista.firstChild);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var elemento_lista = document.createElement('li')
        elemento_lista.innerHTML = keys[i]

        lista.appendChild(elemento_lista)
        localstorage[ keys[i] ] = localStorage.getItem( keys[i] )

        elemento_lista.onclick = function() 
        {alert(JSON.parse(localStorage[keys[i]]))}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the **setInterva**l function. It executes a function of your choice after a pre-determined amount of time.

To do this your DIV must have an unique ID, so we can access it using Javascript's **getElementById()** method.

Here's a simple example, which updates a div with the current time every 1000 milliseconds:

```js
function update() {

  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = new Date();
}
var interval = setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, i will edit the qestion to be more clear.